# Javascript performance of boolean array counting

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, google-chrome-devtools

platform: Chrome 76.

I was performance testing, when I came across the following. The app runs the attached (and prior sieving) code, repeated millions of times.

`t_sieve` is a boolean array, at this point has been fully sieved. This code bit is just counting the false into a int array `t_match` such that at any point the `t_match` will contain the number of '`false`'s up to that array index.

For the image attached, the code takes about 30s to complete out of which 25s happens here. Prior to this, the sieving takes about 4s.

Why? How to refactor this for better performance?

Also FYI, I've repeated the performance profiling and consistently this is where it lags.

[image]

Immediate following block is an update to comments received. Shows how these array are being instantiated ( a bit higher up than the code block following )

```js
const t_sieve = new Array( M_MAX + 1 ) ;
const t_match = new Array( M_MAX + 1 ) ;
```

```js
let cum = 0;
for (let i = 1; i < mod_period1; i++) {
  if (!t_sieve[i]) {
    cum++;
  }
  t_match[i] = cum;
}
const period_match_count = t_match[mod_period];
```

Comment: Can you add your code *as text* instead of an image?  We cannot work with screenshotted code.

Comment: what is mod_period1 and mod_period??

Comment: This will only give a very minor performance boost, but generally negative while loops (`while(i--)`) are more performant than for loops (`for(let i = 0; i < n; i++)`). Though given how long the loop is taking, you would be scooping a cup of water out of a sinking titanic here. And without more info (like what `mod_period1` is) it's hard to give any reliable advice.

Comment: well is `mod_period1` larger than mod_period? If yes, than you are looping too far.... Do you can about the other indexes under it? If no, why waste the cpu..... Hw to make this better really depends on how you use it.

Comment: mod_period1 = mod_period + 1 => the are integers where mod_period1 is the size of the sieve. its an adjustment/shift to start counting from 1 instead of zero.

Comment: So do you need every index in t_match to have a value?

Comment: short answer is yes, because in addition to the 'period' i have to count the 'remainder' as well which can vary.

Answer (score -1):

One thought I had was based on line 190 taking a significant amount of time. The reason is when you add new elements to an existing array in JS it recreates the entire array again. Thus taking exponentially longer each time a new item is added. Check out the performance screenshots:

Here is code that is very similar to yours. Creates an array of 1 million true/false, then counts them just like yours. The performance shows very similar behavior: Alot of the time is spent on line 21 adding the new elements to the array.

[image: Performance Before]

Now check out this restructure:

[image: Performance After]

I replaced line 13 with an instantiation of the array object with a predefined length. Check out how much faster line 21 ran. This is because it already has space and doesn't have to rebuild the entire array the entire time. Granted, there is a trade off. Line 13 took slightly longer, but if you could initialize the size once then you'll make up for it each iteration through the loop.

Comment: You suggested method is how I am instantiating the arrays. I've added that code block to the OP. Even with this method, the proportional "slowness" is maintained ... is what I am observing.

Comment: The posted performance profiles are for the Array instantiation, which I already had in the code.